How to define "Remote process" for Tomcat connection in Firebird
I am writing a web service project with Eclipse, connecting to Firebird database using Tomcat 8 server. Problem is in IBExpert tool, connections from Tomcat show null value in "Remote Process" column, so I don't know which connection comes from Tomcat.

Is there anyway to naming the connections of Tomcat in there? Maybe show path of Tomcat exe file or simply give it a text?
Here the code I use to create connection with HirakiCP library.
public class DBConnection {
    private static final int READ_ONLY = 0;
    private static final int READ_WRITE = 1;
    private static final int CREATE_NEW = 2;

    private static HikariConfig config;
    private static HikariDataSource datasource;

    public static DataSource getDataSource(String dbIP, String dbName,
            String dbUsername, String dbPassword) {
        if (datasource == null) {
            config = new HikariConfig();

            config.setDriverClassName(Constants.DB_DRIVER);
            config.setJdbcUrl(Constants.DB_URL + dbIP + "/" + dbName
                    + "?dialect=3&lc_ctype=UNICODE_FSS");
            config.setUsername(dbUsername);
            config.setPassword(Utility.dbDecrypt(dbPassword));

            config.addDataSourceProperty("cachePrepStmts", "true");
            config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSize", "250");
            config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", "2048");
            config.setMaximumPoolSize(5);
            config.setMinimumIdle(2);
            config.setConnectionTimeout(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(30));
            config.setLeakDetectionThreshold(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(10));

            datasource = new HikariDataSource(config);
        }
        return datasource;
    }

    /*
     * Method to create DB connection
     * 
     * @param dbIP
     * 
     * @param dbName
     * 
     * @param dbUsername
     * 
     * @param dbPassword
     * 
     * @return connection
     */

    @SuppressWarnings("finally")
    public static Connection createConnection(String dbIP, String dbName,
            String dbUsername, String dbPassword, int conType) {
        Connection con = null;

        if (datasource == null) {

            // Create new datasource
            datasource = (HikariDataSource) getDataSource(dbIP, dbName,
                    dbUsername, dbPassword);
        }

        try {

            // Use existing datasource
            con = datasource.getConnection();

            if (conType == READ_ONLY) {
                con.setReadOnly(true);
            } else {
                con.setReadOnly(false);
            }
        } finally {
            return con;
        }
    }
}


Jaybird doesn't know about the cachePrepStmts, prepStmtCacheSize and prepStmtCacheSqlLimit properties you're setting and so those properties are ignored. It seems you have copied this from an example specific to MySQL in the HikariCP documentation. I recommend removing them so you don't make assumptions about features that aren't actually there.

yeah, I actually copied it from an example. Many thanks!

This is not specific to IB Expert (which is also why I removed that tag from your question). This is information reported by the MON$ATTACHMENTS table of Firebird.
When using Jaybird (the Firebird JDBC driver) you have a number of options to set the process name:

Set system property org.firebirdsql.jdbc.processName. For example, by:

Setting -Dorg.firebirdsql.jdbc.processName=Tomcat in the startup script of Tomcat
Using System.setProperty("org.firebirdsql.jdbc.processName", "Tomcat") before initializing the connection pool.


Specify connection property processName. For example, by:

Adding processName=Tomcat in the JDBC URL
Specifically for HikariCP, configuring it with config.addDataSourceProperty("processName", "Tomcat")



See also Process information in the Jaybird JDBC Driver Java Programmer's Manual.
Disclosure: I maintain the Jaybird driver, and wrote parts of the documentation I linked.

Thanks for correcting my question. And double thanks for your amazing answer, it made my day!
